# About Anytime Algorithm

Tags: algorithm

I recently learnt about anytime algorithm but couldn't find any good explanation of this.

Can any one explain about anytime algorithm and how it works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An anytime algorithm is an a class of computational procedures that computes a solution to some problem and that also needs to have three technical properties.
(1) It needs to be an **algorithm**, meaning it is guaranteed to terminate.
(2) It needs to be **stoppable at any time**, and at that time it needs to provide an answer to to the problem (think of this as an approximation to the ideal solution).
(3) As more time passes, the result you get from stopping the algorithm gets **uniformly and continuously better** (i.e. it never comes up with a worse solution, which can happen for some optimization procedures that might oscillate or occasionally restart from scratch).

Answer (score 5):

Traditionally, an algorithm is some process that, when followed, eventually will stop and return a result (think about something like binary search, mergesort, Dijkstra's algorithm, etc.)

An *anytime algorithm* is an algorithm that, rather than producing a final answer, continuously searches for better and better answers to a particular problem. The "anytime" aspect means that at any point in time, you can ask the algorithm for its current best guess.

For example, suppose that you have some mathematical function and you want to find the minimum value that the function obtains. There are many numerical algorithms that you can use to do this - gradient descent, Newton's method, etc. - that under most circumstances never truly reach the ultimate answer. Instead, they converge closer and closer to the true value. These algorithms can be made into anytime algorithms. You can just run them indefinitely, and at any point in time, you can ask the algorithm what its best guess is so far.

Note that there is no one single algorithm called the "anytime algorithm." It's a class of algorithms, just in the same way that there's no one "randomized algorithm" or no one "approximation algorithm."

Hope this helps!